# how generate options for select component dynamically with ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

i am using ant design with react to generate an editable table with a select option inside it
i will fetch the select options using a hook (figbird) which will take some time to fetch but the select will render with no option inside it .
i tried to but the data ( an array of Options) inside a state like this

```
const lines = useFind("lines");
let [lineNumber, setLineNumber] = useState();
const options = {
    lines: [],
  };

  if (lines.error) return "Failed to load resource Machine Status";
  if (lines.status === "loading") {
    options.lines[0] = {};
    setLineNumber[0] = { value: "loading" };
  } else {
    let arr = lines.data.map((line, i) => {
      console.log(i, line);
      options.lines[i] = {};
      return { value: line.line_number };
    });
    setLineNumber = arr;
  }
```

and then render my table and select component inside it

```
     <Formik
          initialValues={{ machine_name: "", password: "", remember: false }}
          validationSchema={LoginSchema}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
          {({ values, handleSubmit }) => (
            <Form {...layout} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Form.Item name="machine_name" label="Name">
                <Input
                  name="machine_name"
                  placeholder="Machine Name"
                  prefix={<TagOutlined />}
                  value={values.machine_name}
                />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item name="machine_line" label="Line">
                <Select
                  prefix={<ClusterOutlined />}
                  name="machine_line"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  value={values.machine_line}
                >
                    {lineNumber.map((line) => {
                    return (
                      <Option value={line.line_number}>
                        {line.line_number}
                      </Option>
                    );
                  })}

                </Select>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item name="url" label="URL">
                <Input
                  name="url"
                  placeholder="URL"
                  prefix={<LinkOutlined />}
                  value={values.url}
                />
              </Form.Item>
              <Row>
                <Col offset={6} span={4}>
                  <SubmitButton>Submit</SubmitButton>
                </Col>
                <Col offset={5} span={4}>
                  <ResetButton>Reset</ResetButton>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              ,
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

but the select still render nothing inside it ... i checked the data returnd from the fetch and it's coming with no error but the state seems like is not been set

Comment: Try and console log the `lineNumber`

Comment: It gives me undefined... If i changed the useState() to useState([]) it gives me [ ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

now it's working by puting the following code after using the useFind (hook that fetch data)

```
if (lines.error) return "Failed to load resource Machine Status";
  if (lines.status === "success") {
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.data.length; i++) {
      options.lines[i] = {
        value: lines.data[i].line_number,
        name: lines.data[i].line_number,
      };
    }
  }
```

after that put the select options

```
<Select
  loading={lines.data.status}
  prefix={<ClusterOutlined />}
  options={options["lines"]}
  name="machine_line"
  style={{ width: "100%" }}
  value={values.machine_line}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Building onto OP jihad.khorfan's answer.

According to antd documentation for the [Select component](https://ant.design/components/select/), the data type should be `{ label, value }[]`. Thus, using value/label is a better choice than name/label, especially when you need to use fields that are not user interface friendly (e.g. IDs) for backend rendering. A small fix is seen below.

```
if (lines.error) return "Failed to load resource Machine Status";
  if (lines.status === "success") {
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.data.length; i++) {
      options.lines[i] = {
        value: lines.data[i].line_number,
        label: lines.data[i].line_number,
      };
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps future developers. Posting a new answer due to lacking reputation score!